# Помощь с директивой ng-repeat и JSON в Angular.js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ng-repeat

У меня есть такой контролер:

```
app.controller('DishIndexCtrl', function DishIndexCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.dishs = [ {
        name_dish: 'Куряча печінка з грибами у вершковому соусі',
        type: 'Гриби',
        img: 'img/001_1_pechinka-grybamy-vershkovomu-sous.jpg',
        ingredients: [
           'куряча печінка - 800 г',
           'печериці - 250 г',
           'ріпчаста цибуля - 150 г',
           'часник - 3 зубчики',
           'вершки 20% - 200 мл',
           'вершки 20% - 200 мл',
           'сіль, чорний мелений перець - за смаком'
    ],
       
    },
        {
            name_dish: 'Яйця Бенедикт',
            type: 'Мясо',
            img: 'img/002_1_yaycya-benedykt.jpg',
            ingredients: [
              'свіжі яйця - 4 шт',
              'булочки для гамбургерів - 2 шт',
              'Бекон або сирокопчений шпондер - 8 тоненьких шматочків',
              'яєчні жовтки - 3 шт.',
              'вершкове масло - 120-150 г',
              'лимонний сік - 1 / 2 - 1 ст. л.',
              'холодна вода - 1 ст. л.',
            ],
        }    
    ];
});
```

Суть такова: нужно что бы было два div (потом больше), в которых есть свои имя, ссылка на картинку и ингредиенты. Имя и ссылку вывел, а от массив ingredients что-то вывести не получается:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="dish in dishs">
             <div class="thumbnail">
                 <img class="img-rounded" src="{{dish.img}}" alt="...">
                 <div class="caption">
                     <h3>{{dish.name_dish}}</h3>
                     <p>
                         <h5>Інгредієнти:</h5>
                         <ul>
                              <li ng-repeat="ingredient in dishs">
                                  {{ingredient.ingredients}}
                              </li>


                         </ul>
                     </p>
                     <p style="text-align: right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" ></i><a style="margin-left: 3px" href="#" >Детальніше</a></p>
                 </div>
             </div>
```

А вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `<li ng-repeat="ingredient in dish.ingredients">`, нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как правильно подсказывает [@Yaant](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574801/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-ng-repeat-%D0%B8-json-%D0%B2-angular-js#comment758339_574801)

Второй `ng-repeat` должен идти по массиву ingredients, который находится внутри объекта *dish*. Сейчас же идет попытка обратиться к свойству массива, но так как такое свойство отсутствует - ничего не выводится.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('DishIndexCtrl', function DishIndexCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.dishs = [{
    name_dish: 'Куряча печінка з грибами у вершковому соусі',
    type: 'Гриби',
    img: 'img/001_1_pechinka-grybamy-vershkovomu-sous.jpg',
    ingredients: [
      'куряча печінка - 800 г',
      'печериці - 250 г',
      'ріпчаста цибуля - 150 г',
      'часник - 3 зубчики',
      'вершки 20% - 200 мл',
      'вершки 20% - 200 мл',
      'сіль, чорний мелений перець - за смаком'
    ],

  }, {
    name_dish: 'Яйця Бенедикт',
    type: 'Мясо',
    img: 'img/002_1_yaycya-benedykt.jpg',
    ingredients: [
      'свіжі яйця - 4 шт',
      'булочки для гамбургерів - 2 шт',
      'Бекон або сирокопчений шпондер - 8 тоненьких шматочків',
      'яєчні жовтки - 3 шт.',
      'вершкове масло - 120-150 г',
      'лимонний сік - 1 / 2 - 1 ст. л.',
      'холодна вода - 1 ст. л.',
    ],
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DishIndexCtrl">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="dish in dishs">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class="img-rounded" src="{{dish.img}}" alt="{{dish.type}}">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{dish.name_dish}}</h3>
        <h5>Інгредієнти:</h5>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="ingredient in dish.ingredients track by $index">
            {{ingredient}}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <p style="text-align: right"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i><a style="margin-left: 3px" href="#">Детальніше</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

У вас **dishs** - это *объект*, а вам нужно выводить ингредиенты из *массива* **dishs.ingredients**

```
<li ng-repeat="ingredient in dishs.ingredients">
   {{ingredient}}
</li>
```